# Sturmey Archer SRF5W lateral axle adjustment

Tags: internally-geared-hub, axle

I have some irritating Long-Shen rear dropouts (deep semi-circular lips around the outside) which are causing problems with fitting a Sturmey-Archer SRF5W internally geared hub.  I would like to shift the axle from the left to the right and would like to know if this sort of lateral adjustment is even possible.

I've looked at [Sheldon's instructions for dissassembly](http://sheldonbrown.com/sturmey-archer/aw.html) and am loathe to take the hub apart unless it's even theoretically possible that it will work.

Anyone had any experience with SA hubs in doing this?  I have about 1cm spare on the left that I'd like to have available on the right by shifting the whole hub body over to the left.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I think I *may* be able to answer my own question with a negative.   After browsing some more I found Aaron Goss's post about stripping down a very similar hub.  [The axle has a raised portion in the center](http://www.rideyourbike.com/images/internalgear/xrd5w.jpg) which would prevent lateral movement.....

I'm going to have to figure out something else.

Perhaps just sourcing a longer axle.
EDIT: Unfortunately I have the longest axle available (see p.56 of [S.A. catalogue 2012-2013](http://www.sturmey-archer.com/userfiles/catalogs/Sturmey-Archer-2012-2013-Catalogue-A0-Low-Res.pdf), which indicates 175mm is max axle length)

Alternatively having a framebuilder cut the dropouts off and replacing them with something saner.

EDIT: Or perhaps bodging up a replacement for the fulcrum arm with it's integrated locating washer ( [HSJ905 on p.41 of catalogue](http://www.sturmey-archer.com/userfiles/catalogs/Sturmey-Archer-2012-2013-Catalogue-A0-Low-Res.pdf)).